# Why can't I deploy my application? (bluemix)

Tags: node.js, testing, deployment, npm, ibm-cloud

There seems to be a problem my `node.js` program that I am trying to deploy on Bluemix. Here are the stages of my `Build and Deploy` on `Dev Ops`:

[image]

First off my test stage seems to be failing with the error:

```
Downloading artifacts...DOWNLOAD SUCCESSFUL
_customer_script.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Finished: ERRORED
```

I have no idea why this is the case, because when I run `npm test` locally, all the tests seem to pass.

But after making passing the test stage optional, the deploy stage fails, rendering the errors below:

```
-----> Uploading droplet (16M)

0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 failing
FAILED
Start unsuccessful

TIP: use 'cf logs modfive --recent' for more information
```

I know for a fact that when starting with `server.js` on my `localhost:3000`, my `JSON` queries seem to be working just fine and the app seems to be running. Therefore I am not sure as to what's going wrong.

Where do I type in `cf logs modfive --recent`. Is it locally on my command prompt, or do I need to connect to the application? Because when the application has not deployed, how do I connect to it?

---

I can't seem to make sense of the error log on Bluemix's dashboard, but here it is:

```
2016-03-18T18:43:49.048+0530[STG/0]ERR
2016-03-18T18:44:09.328+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/server.js:15:19)
2016-03-18T18:44:09.328+0530[App/0]ERR at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2016-03-18T18:44:09.328+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2016-03-18T18:44:09.328+0530[App/0]ERRReferenceError: proces is not defined
2016-03-18T18:44:09.328+0530[App/0]ERR/home/vcap/app/server.js:15
2016-03-18T18:44:09.328+0530[App/0]ERR at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
2016-03-18T18:44:09.328+0530[App/0]ERR ^
2016-03-18T18:44:09.328+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
2016-03-18T18:44:09.328+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
2016-03-18T18:44:09.328+0530[App/0]ERRvar server_port = proces.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;
2016-03-18T18:44:09.329+0530[App/0]ERR at startup (node.js:136:18)
2016-03-18T18:44:09.329+0530[App/0]ERR at node.js:966:3
2016-03-18T18:44:09.347+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
2016-03-18T18:44:09.350+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node v4.3.0
2016-03-18T18:44:09.353+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! modfive@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2016-03-18T18:44:09.353+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the modfive package,
2016-03-18T18:44:09.353+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-03-18T18:44:09.353+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Failed at the modfive@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2016-03-18T18:44:09.353+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR!
2016-03-18T18:44:09.353+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-03-18T18:44:09.353+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm v2.14.12
2016-03-18T18:44:09.354+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-03-18T18:44:09.356+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-03-18T18:44:09.357+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-03-18T18:44:09.357+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-03-18T18:44:09.357+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm owner ls modfive
2016-03-18T18:44:09.360+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-18T18:44:09.360+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-18T18:44:09.440+0530[DEA/0]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-18T18:45:41.110+0530[App/0]ERRvar server_port = proces.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;
2016-03-18T18:45:41.110+0530[App/0]ERR/home/vcap/app/server.js:15
2016-03-18T18:45:41.111+0530[App/0]ERR ^
2016-03-18T18:45:41.111+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2016-03-18T18:45:41.111+0530[App/0]ERRReferenceError: proces is not defined
2016-03-18T18:45:41.111+0530[App/0]ERR at node.js:966:3
2016-03-18T18:45:41.111+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/server.js:15:19)
2016-03-18T18:45:41.111+0530[App/0]ERR at startup (node.js:136:18)
2016-03-18T18:45:41.111+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
2016-03-18T18:45:41.111+0530[App/0]ERR at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
2016-03-18T18:45:41.111+0530[App/0]ERR at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2016-03-18T18:45:41.111+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
2016-03-18T18:45:41.135+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-18T18:45:41.136+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node v4.3.0
2016-03-18T18:45:41.137+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-03-18T18:45:41.137+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! modfive@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2016-03-18T18:45:41.137+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm v2.14.12
2016-03-18T18:45:41.138+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Failed at the modfive@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2016-03-18T18:45:41.138+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-03-18T18:45:41.138+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the modfive package,
2016-03-18T18:45:41.138+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR!
2016-03-18T18:45:41.138+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-03-18T18:45:41.139+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm owner ls modfive
2016-03-18T18:45:41.139+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-03-18T18:45:41.139+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-03-18T18:45:41.139+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node server.js
2016-03-18T18:45:41.139+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-03-18T18:45:41.144+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-18T18:45:41.144+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-18T18:45:41.241+0530[DEA/153]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-18T18:46:45.092+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
2016-03-18T18:46:45.092+0530[App/0]ERRvar server_port = proces.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;
2016-03-18T18:46:45.092+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
2016-03-18T18:46:45.092+0530[App/0]ERR at node.js:966:3
2016-03-18T18:46:45.092+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2016-03-18T18:46:45.092+0530[App/0]ERR at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2016-03-18T18:46:45.092+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/server.js:15:19)
2016-03-18T18:46:45.092+0530[App/0]ERR at startup (node.js:136:18)
2016-03-18T18:46:45.092+0530[App/0]ERR at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
2016-03-18T18:46:45.092+0530[App/0]ERR/home/vcap/app/server.js:15
2016-03-18T18:46:45.092+0530[App/0]ERRReferenceError: proces is not defined
2016-03-18T18:46:45.092+0530[App/0]ERR ^
2016-03-18T18:46:45.113+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
2016-03-18T18:46:45.114+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node v4.3.0
2016-03-18T18:46:45.114+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-18T18:46:45.115+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-03-18T18:46:45.115+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm v2.14.12
2016-03-18T18:46:45.116+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR!
2016-03-18T18:46:45.116+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-03-18T18:46:45.116+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! modfive@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2016-03-18T18:46:45.117+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node server.js
2016-03-18T18:46:45.117+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the modfive package,
2016-03-18T18:46:45.117+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-03-18T18:46:45.117+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-03-18T18:46:45.117+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-03-18T18:46:45.117+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-03-18T18:46:45.117+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Failed at the modfive@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2016-03-18T18:46:45.117+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm owner ls modfive
2016-03-18T18:46:45.122+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-18T18:46:45.122+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-18T18:46:45.217+0530[DEA/4]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-18T18:47:40.097+0530[App/0]ERR/home/vcap/app/server.js:15
2016-03-18T18:47:40.097+0530[App/0]ERR at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2016-03-18T18:47:40.097+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/server.js:15:19)
2016-03-18T18:47:40.097+0530[App/0]ERRvar server_port = proces.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;
2016-03-18T18:47:40.097+0530[App/0]ERR ^
2016-03-18T18:47:40.097+0530[App/0]ERRReferenceError: proces is not defined
2016-03-18T18:47:40.097+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2016-03-18T18:47:40.098+0530[App/0]ERR at node.js:966:3
2016-03-18T18:47:40.098+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
2016-03-18T18:47:40.098+0530[App/0]ERR at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
2016-03-18T18:47:40.098+0530[App/0]ERR at startup (node.js:136:18)
2016-03-18T18:47:40.098+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
2016-03-18T18:47:40.115+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
2016-03-18T18:47:40.116+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-18T18:47:40.117+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm v2.14.12
2016-03-18T18:47:40.117+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node v4.3.0
2016-03-18T18:47:40.118+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Failed at the modfive@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2016-03-18T18:47:40.118+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR!
2016-03-18T18:47:40.118+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-03-18T18:47:40.118+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the modfive package,
2016-03-18T18:47:40.118+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-03-18T18:47:40.118+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-03-18T18:47:40.118+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! modfive@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2016-03-18T18:47:40.119+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm owner ls modfive
2016-03-18T18:47:40.119+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-03-18T18:47:40.119+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-03-18T18:47:40.119+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-03-18T18:47:40.119+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node server.js
2016-03-18T18:47:40.123+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-18T18:47:40.123+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-18T18:47:40.205+0530[DEA/40]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-18T18:48:31.474+0530[STG/0]ERR
2016-03-18T18:49:05.042+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/server.js:15:19)
2016-03-18T18:49:05.042+0530[App/0]ERR/home/vcap/app/server.js:15
2016-03-18T18:49:05.042+0530[App/0]ERR ^
2016-03-18T18:49:05.042+0530[App/0]ERRReferenceError: proces is not defined
2016-03-18T18:49:05.042+0530[App/0]ERRvar server_port = proces.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;
2016-03-18T18:49:05.043+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
2016-03-18T18:49:05.043+0530[App/0]ERR at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2016-03-18T18:49:05.043+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2016-03-18T18:49:05.043+0530[App/0]ERR at startup (node.js:136:18)
2016-03-18T18:49:05.043+0530[App/0]ERR at node.js:966:3
2016-03-18T18:49:05.043+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
2016-03-18T18:49:05.043+0530[App/0]ERR at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
2016-03-18T18:49:05.068+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
2016-03-18T18:49:05.069+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-18T18:49:05.071+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node v4.3.0
2016-03-18T18:49:05.072+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-03-18T18:49:05.072+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-03-18T18:49:05.072+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm v2.14.12
2016-03-18T18:49:05.072+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! modfive@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2016-03-18T18:49:05.073+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Failed at the modfive@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2016-03-18T18:49:05.073+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the modfive package,
2016-03-18T18:49:05.073+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR!
2016-03-18T18:49:05.074+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-03-18T18:49:05.074+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-03-18T18:49:05.075+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-03-18T18:49:05.075+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node server.js
2016-03-18T18:49:05.075+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm owner ls modfive
2016-03-18T18:49:05.075+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-03-18T18:49:05.081+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-18T18:49:05.081+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-18T18:49:05.209+0530[DEA/39]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-18T18:50:10.852+0530[App/0]ERR at startup (node.js:136:18)
2016-03-18T18:50:10.852+0530[App/0]ERR ^
2016-03-18T18:50:10.852+0530[App/0]ERR at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2016-03-18T18:50:10.852+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
2016-03-18T18:50:10.852+0530[App/0]ERR at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
2016-03-18T18:50:10.852+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
2016-03-18T18:50:10.852+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2016-03-18T18:50:10.852+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/server.js:15:19)
2016-03-18T18:50:10.852+0530[App/0]ERR/home/vcap/app/server.js:15
2016-03-18T18:50:10.852+0530[App/0]ERR at node.js:966:3
2016-03-18T18:50:10.852+0530[App/0]ERRReferenceError: proces is not defined
2016-03-18T18:50:10.852+0530[App/0]ERRvar server_port = proces.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;
2016-03-18T18:50:10.872+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
2016-03-18T18:50:10.873+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-18T18:50:10.874+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node v4.3.0
2016-03-18T18:50:10.875+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! modfive@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2016-03-18T18:50:10.875+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm v2.14.12
2016-03-18T18:50:10.875+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-03-18T18:50:10.876+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR!
2016-03-18T18:50:10.876+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-03-18T18:50:10.876+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Failed at the modfive@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2016-03-18T18:50:10.877+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-03-18T18:50:10.877+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the modfive package,
2016-03-18T18:50:10.877+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-03-18T18:50:10.878+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node server.js
2016-03-18T18:50:10.878+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm owner ls modfive
2016-03-18T18:50:10.878+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-03-18T18:50:10.879+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-03-18T18:50:10.882+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-18T18:50:10.882+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-18T18:50:10.959+0530[DEA/21]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-18T18:51:09.806+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
2016-03-18T18:51:09.806+0530[App/0]ERR at startup (node.js:136:18)
2016-03-18T18:51:09.806+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2016-03-18T18:51:09.806+0530[App/0]ERR at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
2016-03-18T18:51:09.806+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/server.js:15:19)
2016-03-18T18:51:09.806+0530[App/0]ERR at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2016-03-18T18:51:09.806+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
2016-03-18T18:51:09.806+0530[App/0]ERRvar server_port = proces.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;
2016-03-18T18:51:09.806+0530[App/0]ERR ^
2016-03-18T18:51:09.806+0530[App/0]ERR/home/vcap/app/server.js:15
2016-03-18T18:51:09.806+0530[App/0]ERR at node.js:966:3
2016-03-18T18:51:09.806+0530[App/0]ERRReferenceError: proces is not defined
2016-03-18T18:51:09.824+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
2016-03-18T18:51:09.824+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-18T18:51:09.825+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm v2.14.12
2016-03-18T18:51:09.825+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node v4.3.0
2016-03-18T18:51:09.826+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-03-18T18:51:09.826+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-03-18T18:51:09.826+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the modfive package,
2016-03-18T18:51:09.826+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR!
2016-03-18T18:51:09.826+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Failed at the modfive@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2016-03-18T18:51:09.826+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! modfive@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2016-03-18T18:51:09.827+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-03-18T18:51:09.827+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node server.js
2016-03-18T18:51:09.827+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm owner ls modfive
2016-03-18T18:51:09.827+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-03-18T18:51:09.827+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-03-18T18:51:09.827+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-03-18T18:51:09.831+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-18T18:51:09.831+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-18T18:51:09.912+0530[DEA/1]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-18T18:52:15.032+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/server.js:15:19)
2016-03-18T18:52:15.032+0530[App/0]ERR at node.js:966:3
2016-03-18T18:52:15.032+0530[App/0]ERR at startup (node.js:136:18)
2016-03-18T18:52:15.032+0530[App/0]ERR/home/vcap/app/server.js:15
2016-03-18T18:52:15.032+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2016-03-18T18:52:15.032+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
2016-03-18T18:52:15.032+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
2016-03-18T18:52:15.032+0530[App/0]ERRReferenceError: proces is not defined
2016-03-18T18:52:15.032+0530[App/0]ERR at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
2016-03-18T18:52:15.032+0530[App/0]ERR ^
2016-03-18T18:52:15.032+0530[App/0]ERR at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2016-03-18T18:52:15.032+0530[App/0]ERRvar server_port = proces.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;
2016-03-18T18:52:15.060+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-18T18:52:15.060+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
2016-03-18T18:52:15.061+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm v2.14.12
2016-03-18T18:52:15.061+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node v4.3.0
2016-03-18T18:52:15.062+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR!
2016-03-18T18:52:15.062+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! modfive@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2016-03-18T18:52:15.062+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-03-18T18:52:15.062+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-03-18T18:52:15.063+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-03-18T18:52:15.063+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Failed at the modfive@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2016-03-18T18:52:15.063+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node server.js
2016-03-18T18:52:15.063+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-03-18T18:52:15.063+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the modfive package,
2016-03-18T18:52:15.064+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm owner ls modfive
2016-03-18T18:52:15.064+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-03-18T18:52:15.064+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-03-18T18:52:15.070+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-18T18:52:15.070+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-18T18:52:15.246+0530[DEA/69]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-18T18:56:25.240+0530[App/0]ERR at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
2016-03-18T18:56:25.240+0530[App/0]ERR at startup (node.js:136:18)
2016-03-18T18:56:25.240+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/server.js:15:19)
2016-03-18T18:56:25.240+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2016-03-18T18:56:25.240+0530[App/0]ERR ^
2016-03-18T18:56:25.240+0530[App/0]ERR at node.js:966:3
2016-03-18T18:56:25.240+0530[App/0]ERR/home/vcap/app/server.js:15
2016-03-18T18:56:25.240+0530[App/0]ERRvar server_port = proces.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;
2016-03-18T18:56:25.240+0530[App/0]ERRReferenceError: proces is not defined
2016-03-18T18:56:25.240+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
2016-03-18T18:56:25.240+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
2016-03-18T18:56:25.240+0530[App/0]ERR at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2016-03-18T18:56:25.259+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
2016-03-18T18:56:25.260+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node v4.3.0
2016-03-18T18:56:25.260+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-18T18:56:25.261+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-03-18T18:56:25.261+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! modfive@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2016-03-18T18:56:25.261+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm v2.14.12
2016-03-18T18:56:25.261+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-03-18T18:56:25.262+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR!
2016-03-18T18:56:25.262+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-03-18T18:56:25.262+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Failed at the modfive@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2016-03-18T18:56:25.262+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node server.js
2016-03-18T18:56:25.262+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the modfive package,
2016-03-18T18:56:25.262+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-03-18T18:56:25.263+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-03-18T18:56:25.263+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm owner ls modfive
2016-03-18T18:56:25.263+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-03-18T18:56:25.266+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-18T18:56:25.267+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-18T18:56:25.345+0530[DEA/194]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-18T19:00:34.555+0530[App/0]ERR/home/vcap/app/server.js:15
2016-03-18T19:00:34.555+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/server.js:15:19)
2016-03-18T19:00:34.555+0530[App/0]ERR ^
2016-03-18T19:00:34.555+0530[App/0]ERRvar server_port = proces.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;
2016-03-18T19:00:34.555+0530[App/0]ERRReferenceError: proces is not defined
2016-03-18T19:00:34.556+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
2016-03-18T19:00:34.556+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
2016-03-18T19:00:34.556+0530[App/0]ERR at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2016-03-18T19:00:34.556+0530[App/0]ERR at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
2016-03-18T19:00:34.556+0530[App/0]ERR at node.js:966:3
2016-03-18T19:00:34.556+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2016-03-18T19:00:34.556+0530[App/0]ERR at startup (node.js:136:18)
2016-03-18T19:00:34.578+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
2016-03-18T19:00:34.580+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-18T19:00:34.582+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node v4.3.0
2016-03-18T19:00:34.584+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm v2.14.12
2016-03-18T19:00:34.585+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-03-18T19:00:34.586+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! modfive@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2016-03-18T19:00:34.587+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-03-18T19:00:34.588+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR!
2016-03-18T19:00:34.589+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Failed at the modfive@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2016-03-18T19:00:34.590+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the modfive package,
2016-03-18T19:00:34.591+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-03-18T19:00:34.592+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-03-18T19:00:34.592+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node server.js
2016-03-18T19:00:34.593+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-03-18T19:00:34.593+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm owner ls modfive
2016-03-18T19:00:34.594+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-03-18T19:00:34.598+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-18T19:00:34.598+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-18T19:00:34.702+0530[DEA/139]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-18T19:07:26.529+0530[App/0]ERR/home/vcap/app/server.js:15
2016-03-18T19:07:26.529+0530[App/0]ERRvar server_port = proces.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;
2016-03-18T19:07:26.529+0530[App/0]ERR ^
2016-03-18T19:07:26.529+0530[App/0]ERRReferenceError: proces is not defined
2016-03-18T19:07:26.529+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/server.js:15:19)
2016-03-18T19:07:26.530+0530[App/0]ERR at startup (node.js:136:18)
2016-03-18T19:07:26.530+0530[App/0]ERR at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
2016-03-18T19:07:26.530+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
2016-03-18T19:07:26.530+0530[App/0]ERR at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
2016-03-18T19:07:26.530+0530[App/0]ERR at node.js:966:3
2016-03-18T19:07:26.530+0530[App/0]ERR at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2016-03-18T19:07:26.530+0530[App/0]ERR at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2016-03-18T19:07:26.548+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
2016-03-18T19:07:26.548+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-18T19:07:26.549+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm v2.14.12
2016-03-18T19:07:26.549+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node v4.3.0
2016-03-18T19:07:26.550+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-03-18T19:07:26.550+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-03-18T19:07:26.550+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! modfive@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2016-03-18T19:07:26.551+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Failed at the modfive@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2016-03-18T19:07:26.551+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR!
2016-03-18T19:07:26.551+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-03-18T19:07:26.551+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the modfive package,
2016-03-18T19:07:26.552+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-03-18T19:07:26.552+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! node server.js
2016-03-18T19:07:26.552+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-03-18T19:07:26.552+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! npm owner ls modfive
2016-03-18T19:07:26.553+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-03-18T19:07:26.557+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-18T19:07:26.557+0530[App/0]ERRnpm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-18T19:07:26.705+0530[DEA/9]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
```

Comment: You can also go the the dashboard, click on your app and then on "logs". This should show you error messages.

Comment: @data_henrik I put up the error log in the question

Comment: I have also taken a few lines of code from the deploy stage to accommodate for lengthy dashboard log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a typo in your program which only surfaces when executing on Bluemix, not local:

```
server_port = proces.env.VCAP_APP_PORT
```

This should be

```
server_port = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT
```

Comment: yeah that was a typo I corrected a while ago. locally I have `process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT` on eclipse, but when I look at the code on DevOps the line seems to be `proces.env.VCAP_APP_PORT` - why would this be the case? and is this also causing the testing failures?

Comment: from where is the code taken that is deployed? Apparently the typo is still in and causing errors. How about closing this question (the typo is causing errors) and re-asking on how to set up the automated deploy?

Comment: But automatic deploy is not my problem here?